# How a loop works in awk ? and do we get matched data from two files?

Tags: shell, unix, join, awk

I am trying to extract data from two files with a common column but I am unable to fetch the required data.

```
File1
A   B   C   D   E  F  G
Dec 3  abc  10 2B 21  OK
Dec 1  %xyZ 09 3F 09 NOK
Dec 5  mnp  89 R5 11  OK

File2

 H   I   J   K
abc 10  6.3  A9
xyz 00  0.2  2F
pqr 45  6.9  3c
```

I am able to get output A B C D E F G but unable to add columns of File2 in between columns in File1 column.

```
Trail:

awk 'FNR==1{next}
 NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}
 {k=$3; sub(/^\%/,"",k)} k in a{print $1,$2,$3,$a[2,3,4],$4,$5,$6,$7; delete a[k]}
  END{for(k in a) print k,a[k] > "unmatched"}' File2 File1 > matched
```

Required output:

```
matched: 
A   B   I  C   J   K  D   E  F  G
Dec 3  10 abc  6.3 A9 10 2B 21  OK
Dec 1  00 %syz 0.2 2F 09 3F 09 NOK
unmatched : 
 H  I   J   K
pqr 45 6.9  3c

Could you please help me for getting this output please ? Thank you.
```

Comment: 1) What is the output of your code? 2) Your code only saves the first field of file2 in the `a` array, but later, you use something like `a[2,3,4]`, which obviously does not exist because has not previously saved. 3) `$a[2,3,4]` is useless.

Comment: `$a[2,3,4]` is nonsense. Do you mean `a[k]`?

Comment: You want to save and print later the fields of lines of `file2` but you only save the first (`H`) and second (`I`) fields in the `a` array.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs, Hi Sir, I want the output in the required output format, but I am getting the output if I implement a[k] is  -   A B A B C D E F G C D E F G

Comment: @Jdamian, Sir, Can you suggest me what need to be there in the print ? It will help me a lot ! Thank You

Comment: Whatever you want to print later, you have to save it before. Thus, `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}` is incomplete. Here you must save what you need print later.

Comment: You probably want something like `NR==FNR{i[$1]=$2; j[$1]=$3; k[$1]=$4;next}`. Then you can reorder the individual columns as needed.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs, I should not use the `k` variable as an array because later `k` is used as a non-array variable.

Comment: you input/output files don't match. `%xyZ` vs `%syz`

Comment: @karakfa, that must be a [typo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error). Key 'X' is very close to key 'S' in a keyboard.

Comment: OK then, is there a separate uppercase Z key?

Comment: @Jdamian Yes, alright, the OP uses `k` as a scalar variable. However, I wanted to use the column names as variable names for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
   FNR == 1 { next }
   FNR==NR {
      As[ $3] = $0
      S3 = $3
      gsub( /%/, "", S3)
      ALs[ tolower( S3)] = $3
      next
      }

    {
      Bs[ tolower( $1)] = $0
    }

    END {
       print "matched:"
       print "A   B   I  C   J   K  D   E  F  G"
       for ( B in Bs){
          if ( B in ALs){
             split( As[ ALs[B]] " " Bs[B], Fs)
             printf( "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", Fs[1], Fs[2], Fs[9], Fs[3], Fs[10], Fs[11], Fs[4], Fs[5], F[6], F[7])
             }
          }

       print "unmatched :"
       print "H  I   J   K"
       for ( B in Bs) if ( ! ( B in ALs)) print Bs[ B]
       }
     ' File1 File2
```

- added non define constraint of ignore case of reference (%xyZ vs xyz)
- need to keep both file in memory (array) to treat at the end. Matched could be done at reading. I keep, for understanding purpose output at  *END* level

Your problem:

- you mainly take reference to wrong file in your code (`k=$3` is used when reading File2 with field from File1 reference, ...)